# Ember not rendering component at first

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm building an Ember app which uses quite a few components. I'm also using Bootstrap. I've got a layout with tabs, and inside the second tab (which is hidden by default), the component (which contains a list of models which have a `hasMany` relationship with the main model) won't render.

I think I tracked this down to Ember Data resolving after the view is rendered, because if I click on another model of the list, these relations will show up.

Some info and details:

I have two main models:

- Image
- Crop

An image can have many crops.

I have an Images/Index controller which has this function:

```
loadCrops: function() {
  var self = this;
  this.get('selectedImage').get('crops').then(function(crops) {
    self.set('selectedImageCrops', crops);
  });
}.on('model.isFulfilled')
```

I added this method because I tried to manually resolve the relationship and get the crops for the image loaded in a variable but I had no luck with this. I'm passing the variables like this:

```
{{image-crops image=selectedImage crops=selectedImageCrops}}
```

This is my Index route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('image');
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model, request) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

If anyone needs more details please, ask for them. Thank you all!

Comment: any reason to not use the setupController hook in your Images/Index route?

Comment: oh, I'm using it to load the array of images. I added it to the question

Comment: Ok, by default setupController already does what you're doing, so you can delete it ("The default setupController hook sets the model property of the associated controller to the route handler's model." -ember docs: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/setting-up-a-controller/). How are you loading selectedImage?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys ```selectedImage: function() {
    return this.get('model').content[this.get('selectedIndex')];
  }.property("selectedIndex")```. `selectedIndex` just defaults to 0, and it stores the current selected index in a list

Comment: ok that begs the question: where are you setting selectedIndex?

Comment: @KoriJohnRoys sorry, I've just edited the reply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82791/discussion-between-kori-john-roys-and-pmerino).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in the end was moving the code to load the crops to the route's `model`, and returning an `Ember.RSVP.hash` with both the images and the crops, and then assigning it to the controller:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  /**
   * Returns an Image instances array
   *
   * @method model
   * @return {Ember.RSVP.hash} Images & Crops
   */
  model: function () {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      images: this.store.find('image'),
      crops: this.store.find('crop')
    });
  },
  /**
   * Takes care of setting the needed variables in the controller
   *
   * @method setupController
   */
  setupController: function(controller, model, request) {
    controller.set('model', model.images);
    controller.set('crops', model.crops);
  }
});
```

Then I added a helper function in the controller to get the current image's crops:

```
selectedImageCrops: function() {
  return this.get('crops').filter((obj) => {
    return obj.image === this.get('selectedImage');
  })[0];
}.property("selectedImage")
```

Thanks to @Karl-Johan Sjögren for the tip on the arrow function!

Comment: That is the old computed syntax, mind if I edit your code?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `function() {}.on()` you are telling Ember to execute that function when an event occurs. `model.isFulfilled` isn't an event though but [a property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#property_isFulfilled) so you need to observe it instead and do a quick check within the method that it really has been fullfilled (so it won't trigger if the promise is restarted for example)

```
loadCrops: function() {
  if(!this.get('model.isFulfilled')) {
    return;
  }
  var self = this;
  this.get('selectedImage').get('crops').then(function(crops) {
    self.set('selectedImageCrops', crops);
  });
}.observes('model.isFulfilled')
```

Also as a side note I would suggest that you use an ES6 arrow function (which retains the outer `this`) instead of using `var self = this`, it's make the code a bit nicer.

```
loadCrops: function() {
  if(!this.get('model.isFulfilled')) {
    return;
  }

  this.get('selectedImage').get('crops').then((crops) => {
    this.set('selectedImageCrops', crops);
  });
}.observes('model.isFulfilled')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to a computed property:

```
selectedImageCrops: function() {
  return this.get('selectedImage.crops');
}.property('selectedImage')
```